# php weird behave notepad++ or character error compile

Tags: php, notepad++, text-editor

**Environment Detail:**

- BitNami WAMP Stack 5.4.26-0
- Windows 7 Professional
- Encoding: UTF-8
  without BOM

I am deployed my project on production server (windows 7). However I found out that something really weird happen to my file.
I try to output the variable. I keep on debugging until I found this weird output.

The WORKING file look like got weird character between the period. The one without weird character between period is **not working**..

From WinMerge:
[image]

From Command Prompt `cat` Command output:
[image]

This is the source file
http://pastebin.com/8C1qj1tn

You cannot see any diff from the browser or paste to the notepad / notepad++, you try to open with WinMerge or cat in command prompt then you can see the line 9 and 20 have the diff. The weird thing is line 20 one work in my production server, but not the line 9..

Comment: Could it be an encoding difference somewhere? E.g. in Notepad++?

Comment: What is your `Line terminator format` in notepad++ in `Settings`?

Comment: encoding is the same UTF-8 without BOM, but weird questions is the one with weird character is working.. not the one normal is working.. my php is 5.4.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically is encoding issue. I use notepad++ click on the Encoding -> Convert to ANSI, then I found out the is a question mark beside the period. (it works like this .?), and also the config file, inside the single quote (') beside the value also have this issue. I am not sure why this funny character will come out.

I got git push / dropbox sync, two different environment working with (Windows / Mac OSX). It request extra careful during with encoding issue.

The solution for me are:

1. Encoding -> Convert to ANSI
2. Fix / Erase the funny / weird character
3. Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8 without BOM
4. Save